# You've forgotten to import "NgxsSelectSnapshotModule" // the NGXS module

Tags: angular, ngxs

**[UPDATE: Ok. We found out how to reproduce, see minimal reproduction]**

#### Description

We see in our server logs many of these 2 FATAL Errors on production and on non-production environments:

- FATAL [main.js:xx] NgxsSelectSnapshotModuleIsNotImported [Error]: You've forgotten to import "NgxsSelectSnapshotModule"! at assertDefined (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:xx:yy) at getStore
- FATAL [main.js:xx] Error: You have forgotten to import the NGXS module! at createSelectObservable (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:1:yy)

We clearly have imported both ngxs modules in AppModule and in the Feature Modules.
In App module:

```
      NgxsModule.forRoot(
      [
      xxx....
      ],
      {
        developmentMode: !environment.production,
      },
    ),
    NgxsRouterPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsFormPluginModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsSelectSnapshotModule.forRoot(),
    NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({
         ...xxx
      },
    }),
    NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot({
      name: 'xxxx',
      disabled: environment.production,
    }),
```

in Feature Module:

```
    NgxsModule.forFeature([xxx, yyy]),
    NgxsSelectSnapshotModule,
```

It is a very huge project with many modules and components... And the errors are only happening via SSR, and there it happens rarely on our dev machines... When it does, though, we see a LOT of Error statements successively while no other component or module is complaing with an error. It is just ngxs.
It seems, that SSR still deliveres the html, and the Angular app loads still well on the client (including all ngxs stuff)

### Minimal Reproduction

Ok. We found out how to reproduce:

1. open a page in browser
2. refresh
3. quickly abort loading
4. quickly refresh again
5. --> many many FATAL Errors

Guess: This might be caused by angular destroying all stuff and both ngxs modules will clear the Injector onDestroy.
As the errors happens ONLY when we reload quickly after aborting (just aborting never creates the errors), it must be sth about angular universal still (re-?) using some components while ngxs already got rid of its injector reference.

https://github.com/ngxs-labs/select-snapshot/blob/0b3b7fea09cd6db9fd7327f2b2710d24391e75a1/src/lib/core/internals/static-injector.ts#L27

### Exception or Error

```
FATAL [main.js:2897] Error: You have forgotten to import the NGXS module! 
    at createSelectObservable (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:1:xx) 
    at AppComponent.get [as progress] (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:1:xx) 
    at AppComponent_Template (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:1625353) 
    at executeTemplate (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshView (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshComponent (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshChildComponents (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshView (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at renderComponentOrTemplate (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx)
    at tickRootContext (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx)

or....

FATAL [main.js:2897] NgxsSelectSnapshotModuleIsNotImported [Error]: You've forgotten to import "NgxsSelectSnapshotModule"! 
    at assertDefined (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at getStore (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at XXXComponent.get [as isXXX] (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at XXXComponent_Template (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at executeTemplate (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshView (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshComponent (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshChildComponents (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshView (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx) 
    at refreshComponent (/opt/app/dist/server/main.js:2897:xx)
```

### Environment

```
Libs:
    "@angular/core": "^11.0.6",
    "@ngxs/store": "^3.7.1",
    "@ngxs-labs/select-snapshot": "^2.0.1",

Browser: only on SSR
```

Comment: One of the errors is thrown from here: https://github.com/ngxs-labs/select-snapshot/blob/0b3b7fea09cd6db9fd7327f2b2710d24391e75a1/src/lib/core/internals/static-injector.ts#L6 More specifically it's because that plugin is doing some special things under the hood: https://github.com/ngxs-labs/select-snapshot/blob/0b3b7fea09cd6db9fd7327f2b2710d24391e75a1/src/lib/core/internals/select-snapshot.ts#L55 (Personally I've moved away from that plugin because I have noticed some odd behaviors and it's not worth the hassle. The cons outweigh pros)

Comment: Thank you for your comment @Richard.Davenport
 
Did you move away from ngxs completely or just from the select-snapshot module?

Comment: Just the select snapshot module. NGXS is awesome, not giving that up.

Comment: @Richard.Davenport can you point out the other odd behaviors and cons you noticed? That would be awesome!

Comment: There was some specific change detection issues that we noticed. I'll see if I can recreate it.

Comment: A possible workaround: Replacing `@Select` with `this.store.select()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The root cause of this issue is this file: https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/packages/store/src/decorators/select/select-factory.ts

The store key that is present in the SelectFactory class is a singleton for the entire server ( it is not an Angular specific singleton ). You can see that from the way it is used inside the decorator: https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/8b52ae654c0a707612a8d23bde4737e69cbb8ee9/packages/store/src/decorators/select/symbols.ts#L11

Because of this if for one user the NGXS module is destroyed at some point and at that point for another user the server-side code is still running the error appears

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/37243777/109517260-bb977f00-7ab1-11eb-9b6c-7c92344b2465.png

I would suggest refactoring this decorator to depend on the Store in every component that is used rather than on the store which is a singleton for the entire server.

Also, this issue is present inside the select-snapshot repository as well and is the same underlying problem with a server-wide singletone ( https://github.com/ngxs-labs/select-snapshot )